# Mouse cursor changing in 32 bit but not in 64 bit

Tags: c++, winapi

From these MAKEINTRESOURCE , GetClassLong ,LOWORD((LPSTR)cursor_name) and LoadCursor is any of them is not compatible with 64 bit? If not then what's the solution, my code is working fine for 32 bit but not in 64 bit, code is a huge applications, main functions used are listed above...
the function has parameter mouse_form

```
  HCURSOR c_cursor, n_cursor;
  LPSTR cursor_name;

    switch( mouse_form )
    {
            case MOUSE_WIN_ARROW:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_ARROW;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_ARROW:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_ARROW;

                         #if (!(defined WIN32) && !(defined WIN64))


        if( environ_get_window_id() != -1 ) cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDCC_ELXHND;

    #endif
                    break;

            case MOUSE_CURSOR:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_IBEAM;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_HOURGLASS:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_WAIT;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_POINTING_HAND:

                        #if ((defined WIN32) || (defined WIN64))
                                cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_ARROW;
                        #else

                cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDCC_ELXHND;
                        #endif



                    break;

            case MOUSE_OPEN_HAND:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_ARROW;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_THIN_CROSS:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_CROSS;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_THICK_CROSS:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_CROSS;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_OUTLINED_CROSS:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDC_SIZE;
                    break;

            case MOUSE_MENU_ARROW:
                    cursor_name = (LPSTR)IDCC_ELXMEN;
                    break;

            default:
                    cursor_name=(LPSTR)MAKEINTRESOURCE( mouse_form );
    }

    n_cursor = environ_wload_cursor( cursor_name );

     #if ((defined WIN32) || (defined WIN64))

    if( environ_control->w_param) 
        c_cursor = (HCURSOR)GetClassLong( environ_control->w_param->awindow,(ELX_LONG) GCLP_HCURSOR );
    else
    c_cursor = (HCURSOR)GetWindowLong( GetForegroundWindow(),(ELX_LONG) GCLP_HCURSOR ); 

    #else
    c_cursor = GetClassWord( environ_control->w_param->awindow, GCW_HCURSOR );
    #endif

    #if ((defined WIN32) || (defined WIN64))

    if( environ_control->w_param) 
    {
    #endif
        if( !n_cursor )
        {
            if( environ_control->win_cptr->window_id == -1 )
            {
            n_cursor = ewcore_control.orig_cclient;
            }
            else
            {
            n_cursor = ewcore_control.orig_cchild;
            }
        }
        else environ_control->win_cptr->prev_cursor = c_cursor;
    #if ((defined WIN32) || (defined WIN64))
    }
        else
    {
        if( !n_cursor )
        {
            n_cursor = ewcore_control.orig_cclient;     
        }
        //else 
        //environ_control->win_cptr->prev_cursor = c_cursor;

    }
    #endif
    #if ((defined WIN32) || (defined WIN64))

    if(environ_control->w_param)
        SetClassLong( environ_control->w_param->awindow, GCLP_HCURSOR,(ELX_LONG)n_cursor );
    else
        SetWindowLong( GetForegroundWindow(), GCLP_HCURSOR, (ELX_LONG)n_cursor );

    #else
    SetClassWord( environ_control->w_param->awindow,GCW_HCURSOR, n_cursor );
    #endif
    SetCursor( n_cursor );
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code which shows the problem

Comment: its not giving the error actually... but okay let me edit my post with code

Comment: Your main problem is that fact that you have utterly failed to perform any error checking on the Win32 API calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation for [`GetClassLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633580.aspx):

> If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle, this function has been superseded by the GetClassLongPtr function. (Pointers and handles are 32 bits on 32-bit Windows and 64 bits on 64-bit Windows.)

In short: Use [`GetClassLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633581.aspx) instead.

From the MSDN documentation for [`GetClassWord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633583.aspx):

> This function is deprecated for any use other than nIndex set to GCW_ATOM. The function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should use the GetClassLongPtr or GetClassLongPtr function.

The same applies to `SetClassLong`, `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`. You need to replace all of these with the respective `*Ptr` variants to write code that is compatible with 32-bit 64-bit versions of Windows.

Also, all your assignments to `cursor_name` are rather awkward. There should not be a cast to a **non-const** `LPSTR`. For predefined cursor ID's a simple assignment should be enough, e.g. `cursor_name = IDC_ARROW;`. For user-defined ID's you have to use `MAKEINTRESOURCE`.

The code that actually loads the cursor is also wrong (for 32-bit and 64-bit builds). You are trying to load a cursor resource that is either a predefined shape (`IDC_ARROW`) or user-defined (`IDCC_ELXMEN`). Predefined and user-defined cursors require different `HINSTANCE` parameters eventually passed to `LoadCursor`. This does not seem to be the case with the code you posted (although you did leave out that part of the code).

Comment: IInspectable thanx a lot bro, i can feel its the right answer, i will try it tomorrow, thanx a lot for your help...:)